# Compare Lines of file to every other line of same file

Tags: bash, matlab, while-loop, nested

I am trying to write a program that will print out every line from a file with another line of that file added at the end, basically creating pairs from a portion of each line. If the line is the same, it will do nothing. Also, it must avoid repeating the same pairs. A B is the same as B A

In short

FileInput:

```
otherstuff A
otherstuff B     
otherstuff C 
otherstuff D
```

Output:

```
A B
A C
A D
B C
B D
C D
```

I was trying to do this with a BASH script, but was having trouble because I could not get my nested while loops to work. It would read the first line, compare it to each other line, and then stop (Basically only outputting the first 3 lines in the example output above, the outer while loop only ran once).

I also suspect I might be able to do this using MATLAB, so suggestions using that are also welcome.

Here is the bash script that I have thus far. As I said, it is no printing out correctly for me, as the outer loop only runs once.

```
#READS IN file from terminal
FILE1=$1
#START count at 0
count0=
exec 3<&0
exec 0< $FILE1

while read LINEa; do    
while read LINEb; do

    eventIDa=$(echo $LINEa | cut -c20-23)
    eventIDb=$(echo $LINEb | cut -c20-23)
    echo $eventIDa $eventIDb
done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f "$1" ] || { echo >&2 "File not found"; exit 1; }

mapfile -t lines < <(cut -c20-23 <"$1" | sort | uniq)

for i in ${!lines[@]}; do
    elem1=${lines[$i]}
    unset lines[$i]
    for elem2 in "${lines[@]}"; do
        echo "$elem1" "$elem2"
    done
done
```

This will read a file given as a parameter on the command line, sort and filter out duplicates, and output all combinations. You can modify the parameter to *cut* to adjust to your particular input file.

Due to the particular way you seem to indent to use *cut*, your input example above won't work. Instead, use something with the correct line length, such as:

```
123456789012345678 A
123456789012345678 B
123456789012345678 C
123456789012345678 D
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the otherstuff is not relevant (otherwise you can of course add it later) this should do the trick in Matlab:

```
 combnk({'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'},2)
```

Comment: That would not work simply because my actual data is several hundred lines long. I just used ABCD as an example

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot it is not too hard to extract the last part of a string programatically. However, for a usefull explanation on how to do that I would need to know a bit more about how the stuff is stored.